# Get non VPN Ip with Powershell or Cmd

Tags: powershell, networking, admin, vpn, system-administration

I need to find out my internet provider ip while connected to vpn. This can be done with request to icanhazip.com, but it will return my VPN(PPTP) Ip, when I need my ISP external Ip.

I need to do it with Powershell or Cmd, it should be automatable. Someone told me that in Powershell there should be a command for web request where you can specify which gateway / interface to use so that icanhazip.com would return my ISP external IP. But I can't find this command.

In my use case I am not allowed to make changes to routes table. And making any changes to configuration of the system. Also I should be able run this script from C# program, this is why I’m thinking Powershell.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is no, you can't do it, because of the way VPN's work and how they are configured.

The main point of a VPN is to route **ALL** traffic through a secure tunnel to a work/other network. It's job is to make it completely look like you are physically connected to the work/other network. That is why icanhazip.com returns your External **Work** IP address, and not your home address. To rephrase, it's like you are asking when I am physically at work, plugged into the work network, "What is my home IP address?"

Also, the IP address you get assigned is usually a "non-routable" address (e.g. 10.x.x.x, 172.16.x.x) that doesn't work on the internet, so it would only route over a work network.

You are right, if you are able to edit the route table, or if your work enables "Split-Tunneling" , or if you are able to Disable your VPN, *then* you may be able to route traffic out your home network, and then get your home IP address, otherwise no.